# Fetching the ID but display the slug in router [symfony5]

Tags: php, router, symfony5

I need to fetch an id and display his slug in my route. But I can't get an uniqueId because it is allowed to have identical slug.
For example, lets pretend I have 2 users in my database (user1 and user2). Both of them want to create an article about ice cream. My route would be :
user1 : /user1/ice-cream
user2 : /user2/ice-cream

I created a voter so user1 cant get access to /user2/ice-cream, same for user2.
Now what I want is to get the id of the article and to display the slug because right now user1 could get
/user1/ice-cream but not user2 (user2/ice-cream) because it will fetch the first data ( which belong to user1).

Right now my route is this one :

```php
/**
     * @Route("/{slug}/{article_id}", name="app_article")
     * @ParamConverter("user", options={"mapping": {"slug": "slug"}})
     * @ParamConverter("article", options={"mapping": {"article_id": "id"}})
     */
    public function index(Article $article,Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager, ArticleRepository $repo): Response
```

How could I get "/user1/ice-cream" which is fetching the id of the article's user 1 instead of this ugly URL /user1/1

Hope I well explained what I was trying to do

Comment: generate a slug for the article based on the title

Comment: Slugs are already generated. If 2 users want to create an article named ice cream, I allow it. And with the slug it will be :
 /user/ice-cream
That's why I want to fetch the id and display the slug, to avoid errors